# tensorflow high validation acuraccy but bad predictions

Tags: tensorflow

I asked this over at stackoverflow but this seems to be the specific place to ask machine learning questions so hopefully I can get more answers. Anyways I am trying to make a multiclassed multilabel neural network. My training result after 20 epoch is **loss: 0.1121 - accuracy: 0.9591** while my validation results are **loss: 0.2006 - accuracy: 0.9405**. I then used model.predict to test things out but the results were quite bad. I even tested on the images I used for training and I got:

```
[0.1367569  0.2681733  0.0271427  0.3046791  0.01867249 0.05539117 0.00498121 0.00070545 0.03091554 0.00495859 0.00811522 0.01736604 0.02292746 0.00100211]
```

But I should of have got:

```
[0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
```

I saw [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47157526/resnet-100-accuracy-during-training-but-33-prediction-accuracy-with-the-same) and changed my momentum but 0.01 but that still doesn't seem to change things much. It said something about using the wrong batch mean so I'm assuming its related to that and somehow training and evaluating is different from predicting? Anyways here is my code:

```
if silence_debug:
    import os
    os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models, backend
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import pandas as pd



#load images
df=pd.read_csv("/content/drive/My Drive/trainlist.csv")
columns = [
    "Atelectasis",
    "Cardiomegaly",
    "Effusion",
    "Infiltration",
    "Mass", 
    "Nodule",
    "Pneumonia",
    "Pneumothorax",
    "Consolidation",
    "Edema",
    "Emphysema",
    "Fibrosis",
    "Pleural Thickening",
    "Hernia",
]
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255.,
    rotation_range=7,
    horizontal_flip=True,
)
traindata = datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=df[:76800],
    directory="/content/traindata/traindata",
    x_col="filename",
    y_col=columns,
    color_mode='grayscale',
    batch_size=8,
    class_mode="raw",
    target_size=(448,448),
    shuffle=False,
)

#load model
if load:
  #load saved model
  print("Loading model")
  model = load_model('/content/drive/My Drive/net_1.h5')
else:
    #create model
    def identity_block(input_tensor, filters):
        f1, f2, f3 = filters
        axis = 3 if backend.image_data_format() == 'channels_last' else 1
        #conv1
        res = layers.Conv2D(f1, (1,1), 1)(input_tensor)
        res = layers.BatchNormalization(axis=axis, momentum=0.01)(res)
        res = layers.Activation('relu')(res)
        #conv2
        res = layers.Conv2D(f2, (3,3), 1, padding='same')(res)
        res = layers.BatchNormalization(axis=axis, momentum=0.01)(res)
        res = layers.Activation('relu')(res)
        #conv3
        res = layers.Conv2D(f3, (1,1), 1)(res)
        res = layers.BatchNormalization(axis=axis, momentum=0.01)(res)
        res += input_tensor
        res = layers.Activation('relu')(res)
        return res

    def conv_block(input_tensor, filters, stride=2):
        f1, f2, f3 = filters
        axis = 3 if backend.image_data_format() == 'channels_last' else 1
        #conv1
        res = layers.Conv2D(f1, (1,1), 1)(input_tensor)
        res = layers.BatchNormalization(axis=axis, momentum=0.01)(res)
        res = layers.Activation('relu')(res)
        #conv2
        res = layers.Conv2D(f2, (3,3), stride, padding='same')(res)
        res = layers.BatchNormalization(axis=axis, momentum=0.01)(res)
        res = layers.Activation('relu')(res)
        #conv3
        res = layers.Conv2D(f3, (1,1), 1)(res)
        res = layers.BatchNormalization(axis=axis, momentum=0.01)(res)
        #shortcut, resizes input so it can be added with res
        shortcut = layers.Conv2D(f3, (1,1), stride)(input_tensor)
        shortcut = layers.BatchNormalization(axis=axis, momentum=0.01)(shortcut)
        res += shortcut
        res = layers.Activation('relu')(res)
        return res

    #model
    layerinput = layers.Input(shape=(448, 448, 1))
    layerlist = layers.Conv2D(64, (7,7), 2, activation='relu', padding='same')(layerinput)
    layerlist = layers.MaxPooling2D((3,3), 2, padding='same')(layerlist)
    #resblock 3x
    layerlist = conv_block(layerlist, (64, 64, 256), 1)
    layerlist = identity_block(layerlist, (64, 64, 256))
    layerlist = identity_block(layerlist, (64, 64, 256))
    layerlist = identity_block(layerlist, (64, 64, 256))
    #maxpool
    layerlist = layers.MaxPooling2D((3,3), 2, padding='same')(layerlist)
    #resblock 3x
    layerlist = conv_block(layerlist, (128, 128, 512))
    layerlist = identity_block(layerlist, (128, 128, 512))
    layerlist = identity_block(layerlist, (128, 128, 512))
    layerlist = identity_block(layerlist, (128, 128, 512))
    #resblock 5x
    layerlist = conv_block(layerlist, (256, 256, 1024))
    layerlist = identity_block(layerlist, (256, 256, 1024))
    layerlist = identity_block(layerlist, (256, 256, 1024))
    layerlist = identity_block(layerlist, (256, 256, 1024))
    layerlist = identity_block(layerlist, (256, 256, 1024))
    layerlist = identity_block(layerlist, (256, 256, 1024))
    #resblock 5x
    layerlist = conv_block(layerlist, (512, 512, 2048))
    layerlist = identity_block(layerlist, (512, 512, 2048))
    layerlist = identity_block(layerlist, (512, 512, 2048))
    layerlist = identity_block(layerlist, (512, 512, 2048))
    layerlist = identity_block(layerlist, (512, 512, 2048))
    layerlist = identity_block(layerlist, (512, 512, 2048))
    #fully connected layer
    layerlist = layers.AveragePooling2D((7,7), padding='same')(layerlist)
    layerlist = layers.Flatten()(layerlist)
    layerlist = layers.Dense(2048, activation='relu')(layerlist)
    layerlist = layers.Dense(14, activation='sigmoid')(layerlist)
    model = models.Model(inputs=layerinput, outputs=layerlist)
    #print (model.summary())
    model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])

#train model
try:
    model.fit(
        x=traindata,
        epochs=1,
        verbose=1,
    )
    print("\nsaving model")
    model.save('/content/drive/My Drive/net_1.h5')
except Exception as e:
    print('\n', e)
```

Comment: Since your classes are disjoint, minimizing categorical cross-entropy would be a more natural loss function instead of binary. How many images do you have per class?

Comment: It varies quite a lot. Some of them only have about 200 images while other have 10,000~20,000. Most are around 5000.

Comment: I tried categorical but the loss stays at around 3 and accuracy stays at around 0.6. Also I tried model.predict on my **training** dataset but it’s still wrong

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, the image generator of Keras works well when combined with fit() or fit_generator() function, but fails  miserably when combined
with predict_generator() or the predict() function.

When using Plaid-ML Keras back-end for AMD processor, I would rather loop through all test images one-by-one and get the prediction for each image in each iteration.

````
import os
from PIL import Image
import keras
import numpy

# code for creating dan training model is not included

print("Prediction result:")
dir = "/path/to/test/images"
files = os.listdir(dir)
correct = 0
total = 0
#dictionary to label all animal category class.
classes = {
    0:'This is Cat',
    1:'This is Dog',
}
for file_name in files:
    total += 1
    image = Image.open(dir + "/" + file_name).convert('RGB')
    image = image.resize((100,100))
    image = numpy.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
    image = numpy.array(image)
    image = image/255
    pred = model.predict_classes([image])[0]
    animals_category = classes[pred]
    if ("cat" in file_name) and ("cat" in sign):
        print(correct,". ", file_name, animals_category)
        correct+=1
    elif ("dog" in file_name) and ("dog" in animals_category):
        print(correct,". ", file_name, animals_category)
        correct+=1
print("accuracy: ", (correct/total))
```
````